# PDO: isset & session not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, isset

I have a password secured page, that can be accessed only with username and password. Everything must be correct but I it doesn't!

this is my form (**index.php**) adn pdo:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['password'])) {

    $dns = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=department_c";
    $option = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO($dns, "root", "", $option);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die("Erreur de connection.");
    }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE name = :name AND password = MD5(:password)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue('name', $_POST['name']);
    $stmt->bindValue('password', $_POST['password']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $nbMembre = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($nbMembre == 1){
        $membre = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        header("location:test.php");
    } else {
        $msg="<font color='orange'>Enter username and  password.</font>";
    }
} else {
    $msg ="<font color='red'>Lgon!</font>";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<label for="name">Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
<label for="password">Passwprd: </label>
<input type="password" name="password" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
<p><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my test page. it's suppous to be secured and accessed with username and password. without `if(!isset($_SESSION['name']))` or if I put it like `if(isset($_SESSION['name']))` I access into the page, but with **!isset** I cannot!

Here is the code (**test.php**):

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
header("location:index.php");
exit();
    }
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
</div>
wellcome
Hellos-.....
<br>
<a href="logout.php"><h2>Logout</h2></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my logout code (**logout.php**):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
 header("location:index.php");
}else{
 echo"<h2> There was a problem with logging out!</h2>";
 exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: you forgot `:` symbol when you bindValue

Comment: the page is accessed anyway, but the poblem is with (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) in test.php page.

Comment: You aren' setting session name in example. Also, that is the ** wrong** way to handle passwords. You should not pass passwords into queries, even with parameter binding and hashing.

Comment: where are you saving $_SESSION info? Perhaps you should assign when user succesfully log in

Comment: `$_POST['name'] = $_SESSION['name'];` then do `if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && !empty($_SESSION['name'])){ // do something } else { // do something else }`

Comment: I pass into the page, but it returnes this error Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 4. and also the logout doesn't  destroyed session !

Comment: @ Anthony: I am a beginner, so I dont know much how should I set password. so what do you recommend?

Comment: Consult my answer below. @KimF Base yourself on that. *Plus*, there is some added information concerning your choice of password storage method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

In your `index.php` file:

Try putting `session_start(); $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];` between `$membre = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and `header("location:test.php");` then follow the conditional statements I put in my original answer.

This I tested and worked for me:

```
...

    if($nbMembre == 1){
        $membre = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
// my addition

session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];

        header("location:test.php");
    } else {
        $msg="<font color='orange'>Enter username and password.</font>";
    }
} else {
    $msg ="<font color='red'>Lgon!</font>";
}

...
// rest of code
```

---

#### Original answer

Base yourself on the following: (test code works as one file)

Assign a variable to the form's POST element, then assign a session name from the `$_POST`.

This would be considered as your login page:

```
<?php
session_start();
// require 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];

if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && !empty($_SESSION['name'])){

    echo "session is set";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $name;

    } else  { 

        echo "session is NOT set";

            }

       } // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<label for="name">Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
<label for="password">Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="password" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="TEST" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then this, your **test.php** as you have it now.

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && !empty($_SESSION['name'])){

        echo "session is set";
        echo "<br>";
        echo $name;

        } else  { 

        //  echo "session is NOT set";
         header("location:index.php");

                }
/* old method
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
header("location:index.php");
exit();
    }
*/

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
</div>
wellcome
Hellos-.....
<br>
<a href="logout.php"><h2>Logout</h2></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Passwords:**

I also noticed that you are storing passwords using [**MD5**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). This is no longer recommended.

Here are a few password storage options:

- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

---

**Sessions:**

Here is an intuitive tutorial on sessions:

- **http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html**

Comment: I guess you mean to put it in test.php,not on the top of the form?

BTW it doesn't return anything, and the session is not still destroyed by logout..

Comment: Run it as it is exactly as shown with nothing else, enter a username and you will see it appear on top. @KimF You can then use the conditional statement inside all your page. This will check if the session is set and not empty. You can modify it to suit your needs. The echo'd name will not have come form the POST, but from the SESSION itself.

Comment: Reload my answer, I've made it a bit clearer and I added what would now be your new **test.php** file. @KimF

Comment: YEAH, in index.php I should post values with form, should I put those command on top of the code that sends values to the DB?

Comment: Only if you'll be using sessions for it, yes. @KimF

Comment: *So*, has this solved the problem? @KimF I tend to think it has.

Comment: From this long period of silence, I figure it either works for you and you're having a great time, or it doesn't and you're trying to figure how to make it work. If it solved your problem, mark my answer as accepted so we can close it. @KimF Otherwise, it will remain in the unanswered category.

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work yet. I put it in several ways in my code, but I didn't vhange anything !

Comment: Try putting `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];` between `$membre = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and `header("location:test.php");` then follow the conditional statements I put in my answer @KimF

Comment: great, it works, except for it returns this error  Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 6.... i can fix it myself thanx for your help. and can you tell me please how to chand MD5 into crypt () for my password? thanx a lot buddy :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. Have a look at the links under **Passwords** in my answer. I have an answer which I gave to someone else about a password-related issue. Once I find it, I will include it here. @KimF

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22389049/) where you can use the password generating function, then look through [`my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22390499/) on the same page. Everything is in there. @KimF If it works for you, you can **+1** the answer but not obligatory.